# iOS: knowing which UITableView Cell was tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have looked around for this issue, and have not found an answer that works for my case. Basically, I have a tableView where each cell contains a collectionView. What I would like to do is to refresh the specific TableViewCell where the collectionView was scrolled, in order to update a label under the CollectionView, within that TableViewCell.

So when the user scrolls on the collectionView, I need to know in which cell that collectionView is. I have tried using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, however, it only is called when the non-CollectionView part of the cell is tapped. When the collectionView is tapped or scrolled, it isn't called. I am coding in Swift.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider changing whole view structure. Putting collection view inside cell is a bad solution

Comment: Why are you putting collection view inside each cells? Do you need horizontal scroll for each cell? Is that your requirement?

For your clue - You can set observer in each cell for collection view scroll and then update the cell's label or collection view's label.

Comment: Yeah I need the horizontal scroll in the tableView cells. How do you set up observer?

Comment: @zellb why is that a bad solution? That's precisely what collection views are for. You can put them anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tag` property of `UITableViewCell`. Set `tag` to `row` number and when cell is tapped, fetch `tag` property to find out the tapped cell index.

Comment: In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, you can get row number as `indexPath.row`. Set this to your `cell.tag`. Now to fetch it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from the tapped cell. To get the value on tap on collection view, you can either fetch the super view of your tapped collection view which is nothing but the cell and then get the tag value from cell. Otherwise you can directly set tag property on collection view.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a architecture issue. Sure it can be done the way you want, but it'd be much easier if your rearranged some things. There is a fundamental problem how you want to do this. You want to manage all of the cells and their collection views directly from your view controller. But this poses the problem of needing to know where messages are coming from and directing messages back to the correct cells and collection views. This will create a lot of bloat that can be fixed with a simple UITabelViewCell subclass. It also is a step in contracting Massive View Controller syndrome. Instead, you should make the individual cells responsible for managing their own collection views.

First off, make the UITableViewCell own and be the delegate and data source of the UICollectionView. This centralizes the data and more closely models the tree of data that you actually see on screen.

```
class CollectionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
        didSet(newCollectionView) {
            newCollectionView.delegate = self;
            newCollectionView.dataSource = self;
        }
    }

    var model: NSArray?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}

extension CollectionTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // configure cell

        return cell
    }

}
```

Now you wanted to have a state refresh when your collection view scrolls. So we're going to add a label to the cell in the prototype cell (Nib or Storyboard.)

```
@IBOutlet var indicatorLabel: UILabel!
```

And you want to update it when the collection view is scrolled. We can do that with the scrollViewDidScroll method off the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. Because UICollectionViewDelegate implements the UIScrollViewDelegate, it's available for us to use since we implement the UICollectionViewDelegate in our extension.

```
// in the CollectionTableViewCell extension...
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollViewOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let scrollViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)
    let completionString = String(format: "%@ / %@", scrollViewOffset, scrollViewWidth)
    self.indicatorLabel.text = completionString
}
```

So by making the individual cells responsible for their own respected collection views, we make managing them easier. It allows us organize our code to be more compact, understandable, and keeps us from getting Massive View Controller syndrome. The more code you can move out of your view controller, the better.

Some good talks to hear on this would be:
[WWDC 2014 – Advanced iOS Application Architecture and Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)
[Let's Play: Refactor the Mega Controller!](https://realm.io/news/andy-matuschak-refactor-mega-controller/)

Answer (score 0):

Your CollectionView will be contained within some kind of cell. Once you have found this cell, you can ask the table for the index. Navigate from your CollectionView up the view hierarchy to find the cell. For example:

```
CollectionView* collectionView = // your collectionView;
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[collectionView superview];
UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[cell superview];
NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:cell];
NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
NSLog(@"rowofthecell %d", rowOfTheCell);
```

Comment: This is generally not encouraged because you never know when Apple is going to change the view hierarchy on you. Heaven forbid you decide to change your own view hierarchy and it all breaks. 